# Exporting MYSQL functions with different access privileges based on creator

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, routines

From phpMyAdmin, I was exporting the functions/procedures used by the user assigned to a particular database and 3 functions didnt get exported because they were created by the 'superadmin'.

I was able to see these functions within

```
localhost > database_name -> Structure -> Routines
```

BUT, I was not able to modify their structure or export them.

The problem was happening because these 3 functions were created by the superuser. When exporting from the superuser account, everything got exported properly.

My question is: as a process, how can I ensure that this doesn't happen again in the future - that someone accidentally creates it as a superadmin (and the site would continue to work fine), but when we try exporting it, the function doesnt get exported (and the new site would stop working).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restricting access to the superuser account would be the first step I would take.  By restricting superuser access you guarantee that no one makes that mistake again.  Is there a reason someone would need to be in the database working as a superuser?

Comment: it was by accident, but it led to a bit of hair pulling on my end as i couldnt fathom the thought that a function _wasnt_ being exported! Just trying to build in a set of processes that avoid this problem again.

Comment: I've seen issues with exporting Views also.  They are often exported as a table instead.